# How to model a self-blocking relationship between users in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am working on a user management system, and I need to model a self-blocking relationship between users. A user should have the ability to block themselves. I'm using UML to represent my system's classes and relationships. I currently have a User class that represents a user in the system. Now, I need to introduce the concept of a user being able to block themselves. How can I represent this relationship in UML?

[image: I have this BlockedUser and user relation it does not make sense i hope some one can help]

i'm thinking that a user should have a relation ship with him self user and that should produce a new class called BlockedUser ??

Comment: Block yourself? What in heaven should that mean? Run against a wall and you have bocked yourself :-/

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: add a self-association between `User`, name it `blocking` (you may label one end `blocked` and the other `blocked by`) and use multiplicity `*` at both ends.

You do not need an additional class, even if you might want an additional table if you'd implement this design with an RDBMS.

If you want to add more information to each blockage, for example the start date, the reason for blockage and, why not, an end date, you may make the self association an association class (dotted line from the middle of the association edge to a class that has the same name as the association).